# Android: Context menu on single click

Tags: android, contextmenu

I have an Intent that extends a ListActivity. In my `onCreate` method after having populated the list adapter I use `registerForContextMenu(getListView());` to register for a context menu.

Now it is working and the context menu has its original function which is; once I click and hold down on an item the context menu opens.

Can I open the context menu on a single click (without having to hold down on the list)?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

call `activity.openContextMenu(l)` onitem click event to open contextmenu on single click and onLongClick  call `activity.closeContextMenu()`

### Example

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MyListView extends ListActivity implements OnItemLongClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Activity activity = null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activity = this;


        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, PENS);
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        ListView lv = getListView();
        this.registerForContextMenu(lv);

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        System.out.println("...11configuration is changed...");
    }

    static final String[] PENS = new String[]{
        "MONT Blanc",
        "Gucci",
        "Parker",
        "Sailor",
        "Porsche Design",
        "item1",
        "item2",
        "item3",
        "item4",
        "item5",
        "item6",
        "item7",
        "item8",
        "item9",
        "item10",
        "item11"



    };



    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        activity.openContextMenu(l);
        System.out.println("...context is called");

    }




    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("...on create context menu...");
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }

    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        System.out.println("...on long click close context menu...");
        activity.closeContextMenu();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: How to inflate custom context menu?

Answer (score 37):

Here is another simpler way to show context menu on single click.

```
private void addOnClickListener()
{
    contactList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
              view.showContextMenu();
        }
    })
}
```

replace contactList by your `ListView` and make sure to call this method after the initialization of `ListView`.

Comment: Cool. This works perfectly with Fragment classes too. Thank you :)

Answer (score 15):

I don't think it's working smoothly. Calling `openContextMenu(l)` will cause `item.getMenuInfo()` to be null (inside method `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`).

You should call `l.showContextMenuForChild(v)` instead of `openContextMenu(l)`.

Comment: showContextMenu will further call showContextMenuForChild.

Answer (score 5):

this work perfect....

```
    listmp3 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.results_mp3);
    registerForContextMenu(listmp3);

    listmp3.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listmp3.showContextMenuForChild(view);
        }
    });
```