# Open ContextMenu on single click

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-menu

I am trying to add a context menu to a linear layout and open it on single click. The linear layout, in turn, contains a textview so that the listener can be invoked when user clicks anywhere on the layout.

Setting onClick listener to linear layout.

```
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And the onClick method:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    openContextMenu(view);
    //view.showContextMenu(); // didn't work as well
}
```

the above method should trigger the following

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){            
     super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);  
     menu.setHeaderTitle("Title");
     menu.add(0, id, 0, "Item 1");
}
```

However, this seems to be not working. From other community posts in here, this is the solution I could possibly find. I wonder if I miss something.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you register the view for context menu via `registerForContextMenu(View)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the context menu for the linear layout using:

```
registerForContextMenu(linearLayout);
```

Comment: oooocuh! I really missed that bit. Nice catch!

Comment: Btw, is there any way not to display context menu on longClick?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435073/android-context-menu-on-single-click